# Display duplicate value of two columns in different rows

Tags: sql

I have a table in which there can be two newspaper publishing dates for a particular value which is inserted in a single column only under NewsPaperDate. All the remaining values get duplicated. Now I have to write a query in which the two NewsPaperDate values should be shown in a single row under two columns, NewsPaperDate1 and NewsPaperDate2, with the remaining values[image]. Can anyone help in this? The DataBase is Sql Server[image]
The Table structure is

Comment: This can be done with a table self-join. What database are you using?

Comment: can u provide table structure? with sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Joining a table to itself is the best approach for your query. Read
>   this

http://www.thunderstone.com/site/texisman/joining_a_table_to_itself.html

Comment: Please duplicate the relevant parts of the link in your answer. This prevents dead links from rendering your answer useless.

Answer (score 4):

You need to join the table to itself. There are different ways of doing this but based on your screenshot you could do:

```
select 
    a.yonja_no, 
    a.newspaper_date as newspaperdate1, 
    b.newspaper_date as newspaperdate2
from newspapertable a, newspapertable b
where a.yonja_no = b.yonja_no
and a.newspapere_s > b.newspapere_s
;
```

(Edited: see comments)

Comment: But this query shows same result by exchanging columns twice. Means first result is newspaperdate1=09/01/2013,newspaperdate2=05/01/2013 and second result as newspaperdate1=05/01/2013,newspaperdate2=09/01/2013. How to show only one column

Comment: oh right. Change this: `and a.newspapere_s != b.newspapere_s` to this: `and a.newspapere_s > b.newspapere_s`

Answer (score 2):

check [fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c130c/2/3) for query execution with sample data

```
create table tab1(newspaperDate number,b number,c number);
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES(1,2,3);
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES(2,2,3);
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES(3,3,4);


SELECT t1.newspaperDate AS date1,t2.newspaperDate AS date2 , t1.b AS b1,t1.c AS c1 FROM tab1   t1 , tab1   t2
WHERE t1.newspaperDate < t2.newspaperDate AND t1.b=t2.b ;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| DATE1 | DATE2 | B1 | C1 |
---------------------------
|     1 |     2 |  2 |  3 |
```

Comment: Hard to follow! Change the column names to match the asker's question and I'll +1